# Javascript RegExp: Match anything but newlines (\r?\n)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have my RegExp match anything but a newline

```
\r?\n
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/(?:[^\r\n]|\r(?!\n))/g
```

This matches either any character except `\r` and `\n` or a single `\r` that is not followed by `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the negative delimiter !

so `(?!(\r|\n))`

try that

or this maybe

```
.+?(?!(\r|\n))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative suggestion why not avoid regexp?

```
var newText = oldText.replace("\r","").replace("\n","");
```

This will return the string removing all the instances of `\r` and `\n`

Comment: Yes, I want to keep them actually, I just want to test for them, then do some manipulation to selection, not remove the newlines

Comment: This will only remove the first occurrence of each string.